# Output Array Contents without selecting each element

Tags: arrays, vba, output

I have the following multidimensional array structure

```
Type Wedge
    C407                As Long
    C417                As Long
    C507                As Long
    C516                As Long
    C607                As Long
    C617                As Long
    C707                As Long
    C716                As Long
    C807                As Long
    C817                As Long
    C907                As Long
    C916                As Long
End Type
```

The above has about 35 elements to it

```
Global myWedge() As Wedge
ReDim myWedge(99, 4)
```

I have populated the array but now want to output the contents of the array to a worksheet.  Previously in other smaller arrays I have outputted each element as below.

```
  'Output IOTT Number and Duration
        For a = 1 To 4
           If YGBL(x, a).IOTT > 0 Then sOutput.Cells(x + 4, IOTTCol) = YGBL(x, a).IOTT
               IOTTCol = IOTTCol + 2
           If YGBL(x, a).IOTTDUR > 0 Then sOutput.Cells(x + 4, IOTTDUR) = YGBL(x, a).IOTTDUR
               IOTTDUR = IOTTDUR + 2
        Next a
```

But given the number of elements I just want to loop through the elements and put this into a sheet without have to do the above for each elements.

Is this possible

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a function....

```
Function PropertyOf(wedgeType As Wedge, index As Integer) As Long
  Dim w As Long

  With wedgeType
    Select Case index
      Case 1
         w = .C407
      Case 2
         w = .C417
      Case 3
         w = .C507
      ....
    End Select
  End With
  PropertyOf = w
End Function
```

Then

```
Dim w As Wedge
For a = 1 To 4
  w = myWedge(x, a)
  For c = 1 To 35
     p = PropertyOf(w, c)
     If p > 0 Then
        ' Do your stuff here
     End If
  Next c
Next i
```

Comment: Huy, thanks for the solution, just struggling with the w = myWedge(x,a)  what is "X"

Comment: I just copy from your sample YGBL(x, a).... so in this instance, you can make another outside loop for x = 1 to 99....